# Does bidi footnote in English need \textLR on inside?

Tags: right-to-left, bidi

In the following example, when I compile, "Footnote in English." is backwards. It is inside a footnote which is inside `\textLR` as follows: `\textLR{\footnote{Footnote in English.}}`
Do I additionally need to put `\textLR` on the inside of the `\footnote`? If I do that, it works. I'm just wondering if this is expected or if this is a bug (because I don't understand why the outsied `textLR` doesn't handle this)?

I don't know how to paste while preserving the arabic, so I additionally link to the file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0d6ya63h1lcdp1/Mixed%20LTR-RTL_Arabi-stadard-font.tex?dl=0).

```
%% LyX 2.3.0dev created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[cp1256,latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{Mixed text Latin and Arabic characters}
\maketitle

\section{Main Text Latin Characters}

This is a paragraph in English.\footnote{A footnote in Latin characters.}
This is a paragraph in English. This is a paragraph in English. This
is a paragraph in English. This is a paragraph in English. \inputencoding{cp1256}\textAR{���
������� ������� �������}\inputencoding{latin9} This is a paragraph
in English. This is a paragraph in English. This is a paragraph in
English. This is a paragraph in English. This is a paragraph in English.\footnote{\textAR{\selectlanguage{arabic}%
\inputencoding{cp1256}%
����� �����.\selectlanguage{english}}%
}\inputencoding{latin9} This is a paragraph in English. This is a paragraph
in English.

\section{Main Text Arabic Characters}

\selectlanguage{arabic}%
\inputencoding{cp1256}%
��� �������\inputencoding{latin9}\textLR{\footnote{Footnote in English.}}\inputencoding{cp1256}
������� �������.\inputencoding{latin9}\textLR{\footnote{\textAR{\selectlanguage{arabic}%
\inputencoding{cp1256}%
����� �����.\selectlanguage{english}}%
}} \inputencoding{latin9}\textLR{Some text in Latin characters.}\inputencoding{cp1256}
��� ������� ��������.\selectlanguage{english}%

\end{document}
```

The output I get showing the footnotes is below:

[image]

The purpose of this question is that I would like to fix [this](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/10110) LyX bug. Note that I know nothing about Bidi.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the `bidi` package? Run the code below using `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\newfontfamily\ARFont[Script=Arabic]{Tahoma}
\begin{document}

\title{Mixed text Latin and Arabic characters}
\maketitle

\section{Main Text Latin Characters}

This is a paragraph in English.\footnote{A footnote in Latin characters.}
This is a paragraph in English. This is a paragraph in English. This

This is a long long long long {\RLE{\ARFont یک کلمه}} long 
long long long long long long long sentence in English.

\begin{RTL}
{\ARFont
این هم یک جمله بلند بلند بلند%
\LTRfootnote{A sample footnote}
  بلند بلند بلند بلند بلند بلند بلند  بلند به فارسی است%
\RTLfootnote{\RLE{\ARFont یک کلمه}}

این هم یک پاراگراف دیگه....
}
\end{RTL}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: gf]

Comment: Thanks, Vahid. Can you add a footnote in English somewhere in the block of Arabic?

Comment: @scottkosty: See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if there are still valid reasons to use pdfTeX. For one, we would not have to assume that the user (whoever wants to compile a .tex file) has the Tahoma font available. I'll leave this question open because I'm interested in a pdfTeX answer. Your answer is still useful and we might implement your suggestion for our export that uses XeTeX.